# find the error in this android code

Tags: android

The app shows ANR(App Not Responding) dialog on pressing the start button.
The motive of this app is to find the distance traveled by the use or phone approximately. I have not used time of clock but it is just to check the app is working 
Thanks in advance

Java Code

```
    package com.skydiver.distancecalculator;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.Locale;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    //Objects to access the sensors in the device
    Sensor accelero ;
    SensorManager manager;

    float currentAcc, lastAcc=0.0f, effectiveAcc;
    float distance = 0, totalDistance = 0;
    int time_elapsed = 0;

    //Text fields to show the value of acceleration,time and distance travelled
    TextView accX, accY, accZ, dist_total, dist_last, time;

    //Variables to store the value of acceleration in X,Y and Z directions
    public float val_accX, val_accY, val_accZ;

    //Buttons for starting and stopping the distance Calculations
    Button startButton, stopButton, resetButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Binding Button  in the java code with the layout widgets
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        resetButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

        //Getting the Sensor service using sensor manager object to access the accelerometer sensor in device
        manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelero = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        //Check if there is an accelerometer sensor present on the Device
        if(accelero == null){
            //Displays a message to the user that sensor is not present
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sensor Not Present on Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Registering the sensor manager to listen to the sensor events at 10ms
        manager.registerListener(this, accelero, 10000);

        //Binding Textviews  in the java code with the layout widgets
        accX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_accX);
        accY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_accY);
        accZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_accZ);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        dist_last = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_last_dist);
        dist_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_total_dist);

        //Setting the function on click action of buttons
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetFields();
            }
        });
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetFields();
                calculate();
            }
        });
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopCalculation();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        //Unregister the listener if the user moves to another activity or app
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        //Resume the listener on resuming of the activity
        manager.registerListener(this,accelero, 10000);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //Getting the changed values of the sensors in the variables
        val_accX = sensorEvent.values[0];
        val_accY = sensorEvent.values[1];
        val_accZ = sensorEvent.values[2];

        //Calling the function to calculate the total distance travelled
        calculate();
        //Display the current acceleration values to the user
        displayValues();

    }

    public void calculate() {

        while (true){
            currentAcc = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(val_accZ,2)+Math.pow(val_accZ,2)+Math.pow(val_accZ,2) - Math.pow(9.80665,2));
            effectiveAcc = currentAcc - lastAcc;
            distance = Math.abs(effectiveAcc) * 0.5f * time_elapsed * time_elapsed ;
            totalDistance += distance;
            lastAcc = currentAcc;
            time_elapsed +=1;

            if (stopButton.isPressed()) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private void stopCalculation(){
        dist_total.setText(String.format("Total Distance: " + "%s" + " m", Float.toString(totalDistance)));
        //time.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"Time: " + "%d" + " s", time_elapsed));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    public void resetFields(){
        time.setText(R.string.time_0_0);
        dist_last.setText(R.string.distance_0_0);
        dist_total.setText(R.string.total_distance_0_0);
    }

    public void displayValues(){
        accX.setText(String.format("Acceleration X: " + "%s" , val_accX));
        accY.setText(String.format("Acceleration Y: " + "%s" , val_accY));
        accZ.setText(String.format("Acceleration Z: " + "%s" , val_accZ));
    }
}


XML File
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.skydiver.distancecalculator.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/acceleration_x_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_accX" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/acceleration_y_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_accY" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/acceleration_z_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_accZ" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/time_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_time" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/distance_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_last_dist" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/total_distance_0_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_total_dist" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:text="@string/reset_fields"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.skydiver.distancecalculator" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Well, this is rarely a good idea `while (true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a bit on @Karakuri's answer:  sensor events come in on the main thread.  You're meant to handle them quickly and return control to the OS.  By looping forever in it, you're preventing the main thread from doing anything, including respond to Android lifecycle events, redraw, or process the next sensor event.  You're eventually killed by a watchdog timer that looks for cases of the UI thread being stuck and kills the application.

You need to rearchitect your app.  No loop.  When you want to stop responding to events, unregister from them.  When you want to start listening again, reregister.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the prompt help. The problem is in the loop. And also the part on threading @Gabe Sechan gave an insight into the origin of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line with `while (true) {` and the corresponding closing bracket. You only need the contents of the loop to execute once with each sensor update.

Remove these lines as well, because this `if` statement will only be true if the user is literally holding the stop button down at the moment it executes:

```
 if (stopButton.isPressed()) {
     break;
 }
```

Unless you have a need for the sensor values outside of running the calculation, you should wait until the start button is pressed before calling `SensorManager.registerListener()` and you should call `SensorManager.unregisterListener()` when the stop button is pressed (which is why you don't need the above `if` statement). Otherwise you will will be receiving sensor values when you do not need them and running the accelerometer more than necessary.